# Abort with getReponseCode();

Tags: java, android, json, httpurlconnection

The following script will run, but will not provide any data. In the manifest, the permission for Internet and Network State was entered.

When debugging, he leaves the method getFromServer() in the line

```
final int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode ();
```

There is no error message. Can you help me to find my mistake? The URL is correct and can be accessed through the browser.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DoIt doIt = new DoIt();
        doIt.execute("Example");
    }

    public class DoIt extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String url = "http://example.com/example.php";
            String response = "";

            try {
                response = new GetData().getFromServer(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute(): " + s);
        }
    }

    public class GetData {
        public String getFromServer(String url) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Log.d(TAG, "URL: " + url);
            URL _url = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();

            final int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                String line;

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "getFromServer()", e);
                }
            }

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're getting 404 status code and your StringBuilder doesn't have any data. Here is what I'm getting from curl

`curl -I http://example.com/example.php
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 09 Nov 2017 22:24:01 GMT
Expires: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 22:24:01 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 07 Nov 2017 13:09:40 GMT
Server: ECS (oxr/83B4)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: 404-HIT
Content-Length: 1270`

Answer (score 0):

the URL is an example url, that's why it says "example.com". For my URL, which I do not want to publish here, comes back the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 07:12:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.27
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
Upgrade: h2c
Connection: Upgrade
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```